# Wordpress - URL wild card id loads root permalink

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a Wordpress page called "Design" with the permalink "/design"

It loads as expected. What I am trying to do is to tell wordpress or my htaccess file that if I want to go to a url like:

```
domain.com/design/123abc
```

It will still load the /design permalink but keep the "123abc" appened to the url. I am not looking for a redirect. I just want wordpress to load the page and ignore everything after "/design/"

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer. Added this script in my child theme functions.php

24565 is the id of the /design page

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
   add_rewrite_rule('^design/*', '/index.php?page_id=24565', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```